# MySQL query: how to construct query which contains name of the event and name of the corresponding place

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have two InnoDB tables: 'places' and 'events'. One place can have many events, **but** event can be created without entering place. In this case event's foreign key is NULL.

Simplified structure of the tables looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `places_id` int(9) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_events_places` (`places_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE `events`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `events_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`places_id`) REFERENCES `places` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `places` (
  `id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Question is, how to construct query which contains name of the event and name of the corresponding place **(or no value, in case there is no place assigned?)**.

I am able to do it with two queries, but then I am visibly separating events which have place assigned from the ones that are without place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT events.col1, events.col2, places.name
   FROM events LEFT OUTER JOIN places
      ON events.places_id = places.id
```

In an OUTER JOIN, the table on the left (or right, for RIGHT OUTER JOIN) controls the result set.  Matching values from the other table are supplied where a match can be found, otherwise those values are NULL.